# How to hook vim's window resize event?

Tags: window, vim

If I have a window with vim in it (windows that the window manager uses, not the vim windows), and then do a :vsp or :sp, then resize my window, the splits will not resize.  I'd like, that when the window vim is in is resized, for the splits to be resized accordingly (ie. =).

I'm using gvim, but this should probably apply to both vim and gvim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a `VimResized` event available for autocommands, so you can use:

```
autocmd VimResized * exe "normal \<c-w>="
```

This seems to work fine with gvim, and for shrinking a terminal-based vim. But there's a bit of an issue with enlarging vim within a terminal, it doesn't redraw properly until some other action is taken.